# NextJs mqtt app client does not update context in event handlers

Tags: web, next.js, mqtt, iot, broker

I am developing mqtt web client for an IOT project using NextJs and mqtt package. In order to allow the client object to be shared among all components, I implemented a context API in which I defined some states as seen in the code below. The issue I am having here is, anytime I make update to `msg` state using `setMsg` function in the 'message' event handler, the msg does not get updated.

If I also try to publish a message by clicking a button, the message is not published. The only I was able to publish is by calling the `client.publish` intermittently inside `setInterval`

I am using the shiftr.io mqtt broker and I see an error stating that connection failed even though the shiftr.io dashboard indicated that connection is established by showing the client with its ID.

Thank you in advance.

** index.js file:**

```
import Car from '../components/Car';
import CarList from '../components/CarList';
import Board from '../components/Board';
import Notification from '../components/Notification';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../lib/context';
import mqtt from 'mqtt'
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  
  // console.log(JSON.parse(client).connected)
  const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://tatwo:K1FADvdffhfff@tatwo.cloud.shiftr.io', {
    clientId: 'client1'
  })

  const [freeSpace, setFreeState] = useState(1)
  const {setSpaceStatus, setMqttClient, mqttClient, setMsg, msg} = useGlobalContext()
  const [spaceMessageString, setSpaceMessageString] = useState(['0','0','0'])

  const publishStatus = (msg, clt)=>{
      client.publish('/reservation', msg)
  }

  if(client){
    setMqttClient(client)
  }

  client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connected')
    client.subscribe('space')
  })

  client.on('message', function(topic, message){
    console.log('receieved: ', message.toString().split(','))
    // setSpaceMessageString(message.toString().split(','))
    setMsg(message.toString())
    // setSpaceStatus(message.toString().split(','))
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    return ()=>{
        if(mqttClient){
          mqttClient.end()
        } 
    }

  }, [spaceMessageString])

   
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
      <h1 className='text-white text-3xl md:text-5xl font-extrabold text-center'>Parking without stress</h1>
      <p className='text-amber-500 text-lg my-5'>Use smart parking system to check for parking space before you drive. </p>
      <Board />
      <p>{msg}: {mqttClient?.connected == true ? 'Onlined': 'offline'}</p>
      {
        freeSpace === 0 ?
        // <Notification /> : <CarList spaceMessageString={spaceMessageString} />
        <Notification /> : (
          <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4 my-5 w-full'>
            {
              spaceMessageString.map((space, index)=>  
                <Car 
                  name={`Space ${index + 1}`} 
                  message={spaceMessageString[index]} 
                  key={index}
                  identity={index + 1}
                  publishStatus={publishStatus}
                />
              )
            }
        </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )

}
```

** context.js: **

```
import React from 'react'
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

const AppContext = createContext({});

const AppProvider = ({children}) => {


    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [reservations, setReservations] = useState([])
    const [spaceStatus, setSpaceStatus] = useState([1, 0, 0])
    const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false)
    const [mqttClient, setMqttClient] = useState(null)
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('no message')

    const client = null;

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={
            {
                user, 
                setUser, 
                spaceStatus, 
                setSpaceStatus,
                reservations,
                setReservations,
                connected, 
                setConnected,
                client,
                setMqttClient,
                mqttClient, 
                setMsg, 
                msg
            }
        }>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export default AppProvider
```

** _app.js: **

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import AppProvider from '../lib/context';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
  
    <AppProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AppProvider>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure you change the username and password now you have shared them with the whole internet. Also make sure that the broker you are connecting to support MQTT over WebSockets on port 80 as the ` mqtt://` connection is getting automatically converted to `ws://` due to being run in the browser.

Comment: The username and password are not the actual ones I use. Like you mentioned, I believe the broker does not support MQTT over websocket, because my Esp8266 microcontroller communicates well with the same broker via the same URL.  Thank you, @hardillb

Comment: If the broker doesn't support MQTT over WS then this code will never connect (You can ONLY use MQTT over WebSockets from the web browser)